# Can I access settings defined in other json files from tasks.json in VSC?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, task

I want to create tasks.json file in VSC.
I know how to access predefined variables, environment variables, configuration variables... this is all nicely explained in [variables reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) page.
But I have some configuration in another json files in my project - is there a way to access them?
For the time being I just replicated the settings I need into settings.json - so I can access them like any other configuration variables - but this does not look right.
Here is what I mean:
I added the following to settings.json

```
"tq.appName" : "App Name",
"tq.appPublisher" : "Pub Name",
"tq.appVersion" : "1111111111",
"tq.targetDockerContainerName": "docker"
```

Then I can access them in my task:

```
        "label": "Build APP and replace/publish in docker image",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${workspaceFolder}\\.vscode\\DevelopingDaily.ps1",
        "args": [
            {
                "value": "${config:tq.appName}",
                "quoting": "strong"
            },
            {
                "value": "${config:tq.targetDockerContainerName}",
                "quoting": "strong"
            },
            {
                "value": "${workspaceFolder}\\${config:tq.appPublisher}_${config:tq.appName}_${config:tq.appVersion}.app",
                "quoting": "strong"
            }
        ]
```

But those values are stored in app.json file in project - not in settings.json.  I would prefer to get the values directly from app.json - without the need to copy them over into settings...
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content-json-property) command `extension.commandvariable.file.content`

Using `config.json` file

```
{
  "log": "foobar.log",
  "server1": {
    "port": 5011
  },
  "server2": {
    "port": 5023
  }
}
```

In your tasks.json you want to use the server1 port value.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo Server1Port",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo",
      "args": [
        "${input:configServer1Port}"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "configServer1Port",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
      "args": {
        "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/config.json",
        "json": "content.server1.port",
        "default": "4321"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!